# Php multiple image uploader with class

Tags: php

What am i doing wrong? I cannot send multiple files, only one. I cannot pass an array multiple files into a function.

Uploading files to the server and saving into sql database - it works.

**form**

`<input type="file" name="product_images[]"`

**new.php**

```
$photo_multi = new Photographmultiple();

$id = $database->insert_id;

$files = 'product_images';

$photo_multi->upload_file($files, $id);
```

**class Photographmultiple**

```
public function upload_file($field_name, $id) {

    if(isset($_FILES[$field_name])) {

        foreach ($_FILES[$field_name]['name'] as $key => $val) {

            $image = ($_FILES[$field_name]['name'][$key]);
            $target_path = $this->upload_dir . '/' . $image;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name'][$key], $target_path);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . self::$table_name . " (";
            $sql .= "product_id, product_images";
            $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
            $sql .= self::$database->escape_string($id) . "', '";
            $sql .= self::$database->escape_string($image) . "')";
            //echo $sql;
            $result = self::$database->query($sql);
            return $result;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed from `public function upload_file` `return $result;` and everything works, I can send now multiple files.